# Feedback on my bash backup script

Tags: bash, shell

I have this little server at home, which is hosting some websites, school stuff and a minecraft server. I made this backup script and I would like some feedback since I'm not very good at scripting.

```
#!/bin/bash
# declare folders to backup
dirs=(
    "/home/ferre/Minecraft"
    "/var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily"
);

# backup names
names=(
  "Minecraft"
  "Mysql"
);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

# backup folder
backupdir="/mnt/backup";

# backup algorithm
for (( i=0; i<=$(( ${#dirs[*]} -1 )); i++))
do
  # info
  echo "starting backup of ${names[i]}";

  # create folder
  path="${backupdir}/${names[i]}";
  $(mkdir -p "$path");

  # create backup
  file="${path}/$(date +%F).tar";
  $(tar -czf "$file" --absolute-names "${dirs[i]}");

  # reporting
  result=$?;
  if [ $result -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "SUCCESS";
  elif [ $result -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "WARNING some files where changed while copying!";
  else
    echo "FATAL ERROR";
  fi
done
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Are you running this manually or by automatic (cron) timed job?

Comment: This is running by a cron job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a lot to say, the script is fairly simple.

For the date format:

```
file="${path}/$(date +%F).tar";
```

I think I would define a **constant** variable at the top of the code. You might want to change the pattern latter (use something different than `YYYY-MM-DD`).

This:

```
$(mkdir -p "$path");
```

can simply be written as:

```
mkdir -p "$path"
```

unless you want to save the output of the `bash` command to a variable but this is not the case here.

---

You have some key/pair values to define your backup sources:

```
dirs=(
    "/home/ferre/Minecraft"
    "/var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily"
);

# backup names
names=(
  "Minecraft"
  "Mysql"
);
```

I would combine both into an **associative array**.

```
declare -A sources=(
    ["Minecraft"]="/home/ferre/Minecraft"
    ["Mysql"]="/var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily"
)

for item in "${!sources[@]}"; do
  echo "Name: $item => Directory: ${sources[$item]}"
done
```

Output:

```
Name: Mysql => Directory: /var/lib/automysqlbackup/daily
Name: Minecraft => Directory: /home/ferre/Minecraft
```

Thus you can easily loop on the array and extract name and target directory. Warning: please check the syntax. Bash has many pitfalls and I may have made mistakes.

---

**Logging**: I think it is important to retain a trace of script execution. Especially when the script is unattended. The console can quickly fill up and you could miss critical messages.

You have a few options like:

- define a variable for a log file then use `tee -a next` next to each command, so that you get output to console and to a file at the same time. But this is tedious and not flexible.
- Call your script like this: `/path/to/your/script.sh > backup.log` (use `>>` to append) or: `/path/to/your/script.sh | tee backup.log`
- or better yet `/path/to/your/script.sh 2>&1 | tee backup.log` to capture the output of stderr.

Last but not least, your script could return an **exit code**. This is useful if your script is going to be handled by another script or even set up as a service.

---

Suggestions:

- Have the script send you the log file by E-mail after execution. Or archive the log file somewhere for later review if desired.
- Add **error handling** to make your script more reliable and more robust. If something wrong happens, or at least a fatal error, the script should stop and alert you. Here is an intro: [Bash Error Handling](https://linuxhint.com/bash_error_handling/)

A backup script is usually critical, it has to perform reliably. One day, you may need to restore some important files, or recover from a system crash. There is nothing more tragic than useless/incomplete backups.

So you should also **test your backups** manually from time to time. Attempt to restore a random file and verify the result.

Comment: Can you split the `declare -A` into multiple lines? This would make them easier readable.

Comment: I don't think the date format will ever change. Once you have come to the ISO format, there's no reason to change to anything else.